# How can I evaluate expressions for debugging in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging

One feature I really appreciate in PyCharm is the evaluate expression window, where I can evaluate an expression and a block of code at breakpoint. I am wondering whether there is an equivalent / similar feature in Xcode for IOS development.

I have tried the following which does not give me what I need:

1. using "print" command in the debug console
2. using PO command to print object in debug console.
3. inserted "expression" in debug console.
4. Insert break point before and after the block of code which I want to evaluate

What I really need if possible is:

1. To be able to evaluate a block of code (after which, the value of the variables will be updated in the "variable watch window".
2. Change the expression / block of code to be evaluated at run time.
3. Once at break point, evaluate a block of code after the break point multiple times, without running the code before the break point again (this is the issue with inserting two breakpoints before and after the block of code, because I need to re-run the code before the first break point if I want to change my expression / block of code)

Comment: You can do a lot of this with lldb in the debugger window. You can even switch it from lldb mode to swift mode with :swift which will give you the ability to work in a more natural programming way. Look at the 'breakpoint add command' and 'autocontinue' in lldb to print out code at running.

Comment: AIBlue's comment has been very helpful and for anyone who is interested, I found a book called "Advanced Apple Debugging and Reverse Engineering" after digging a bit more into what AIBlue said about LLDB. Appreciate it.